# How to retrieve the nodes with multiple relationships using cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can some one please help me on this.

I am using cypher query  to get the nodes that are having relationship as either 'hive' or 'hadoop' and i am able to get the nodes.

but when i try to get the nodes that are having relationship as both 'hive' and 'hadoop' i am not able to get the nodes.

This is the query i am using

start n=node(*) match (n)-[r]-() where type(r)="Hadoop" and type(r)="hive" return n,count(n);

This query returns 0 rows.

Is my query wrong or do i need to do it the other way.

Thanks in advance.

Gouse

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
start n=node(*) match ()-[:Hadoop]-(n)-[:hive]-() return n,count(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your query should be:

> start n=node(*) match (n)-[r1]-(),(n)-[r2]-() where type(r1)="Hadoop"
>   and type(r2)="hive" return n,count(n);

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this

```
match (n)-[r:Hadoop|hive]-()
return n,count(n);
```

It will provide you what you are expecting. It is better to conditions in match rather to have it in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason your query gets no results is because the part `where type(r)="Hadoop" and type(r)="hive"` says you are looking for an instance of r where r.type = "Hadoop" and "hive" simultaneously. Since r.type can only have one value at any time, it is impossible for it to equal Hadoop and Hive at the same time; so the statement can be logically simplified to "where false" or basically, drop all matches.

If you are looking for all nodes that have either relationship, than [Satish Shinde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29049394/6893866) is the right way to specify it

```
match (n)-[:Hadoop|hive]-()
return n,count(n);
```

Or, with direction

```
match (n)-[:Hadoop|hive]->()
return n,count(n);
```

If you need BOTH to be present, than you need to match two separate relationship edges like follows

```
match ()-[:hive]-(n)-[:Hadoop]-()
return n,count(n);
```

Or, with direction

```
match ()<-[:hive]-(n)-[:Hadoop]->()
return n,count(n);
```

And for completeness, if you want to check both exist in a where close, you can use [remigio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15159363/6893866)

```
start n=node(*) match ()-[r2]-(n)-[r1]-() where type(r1)="Hadoop" and type(r2)="hive" return n,count(n);
```