# Find node having two distinct relationship in Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, relationship

I am a newbie in Cypher. I am trying to find a query which will returns nodes having more than one relationship to other nodes.
Please refer to http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/images/cypher-match-graph.svg for the structure.
I am trying to find the person who has acted in some movie(s) and also a father. 
When I am running below query, it is giving me 0 records:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
WHERE type(r)="ACTED_IN" AND type(r)="FATHER"
RETURN n,count(n);
```

However, when I am running below query, it does return data but that I think is not what I wanted:

```
START n=node(*)
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
WHERE type(r)="ACTED_IN" OR type(r)="FATHER"
RETURN n,count(n);
```

So basically, I need a query which will fetch only **Charlie Sheen** since he acted in **Wall Street** movie and also father of **Martin Sheen**

I have tried to follow what others are saying in [Cypher query to find nodes that have 3 relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403142/cypher-query-to-find-nodes-that-have-3-relationships) or [How to retrieve the nodes with multiple relationships using cypher query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159100/how-to-retrieve-the-nodes-with-multiple-relationships-using-cypher-query) or [Cypher query to find nodes that have 3 relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403142/cypher-query-to-find-nodes-that-have-3-relationships) but not able to fathom the trick :(

Any help will be of much appreciation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to query this is:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(), (p)-[:FATHER]->()
RETURN p
```

You're looking for a `:Person` node having and ACTED_IN relationship and (since `p` is used again) having a `:FATHER` relationship. I'm using anonymous nodes at the other end, since we're not interested in the endpoint - just the fact that it is connected is interesting.

An alternative way to express that:

```
MATCH ()<-[:FATHER]-(p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()
RETURN p
```

Note that you shouldn't use `START` (unless querying manual indexes) any more.

Comment: Wow ! That was great :). Thanks.
BTW, can you please suggest me from where I can get in-depth knowledge of Cypher ? I am following their online tuts but not able to figure out everything....

Comment: Hi Stefan, your query worked well. However if I need to put an OR between these two conditions then what should be the query ? 
I mean, I want to find list of persons who either acted in a movie or parent of some other person...

Comment: use the pipe for matching multiple reltype: `match (a)-[:TYPE1|:TYPE2]->(b)`